# Bash -nt compare to distingiush between Access, Modify, Change?

Tags: bash, unix-timestamp

In Bash the -nt test compares **Modify** time

> -nt   newer than   (modification date-time of file)

like here

```
if [ file_a -nt file_b ]; then
fi
```

Is there a way to compare **Access** time or **Change** time?

Comment: Normally, Modify=Change, Do you mean file Create time? The only way I can see to solve that is parse output of expanded `ls -l..?somethin? ` that includes Access or Create times. Good luck.

Comment: Note that I'm here because it very definitely compares by Change time.  Change gets updated when the file is modified, but it seems it can also get updated by underlying filesystem changes that have nothing to do with the file contents, like apparently mounting and unmounting the filesystem...   so I'm having to find something more reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) to access the atime and ctime:

```
nt () {
    local OPTIND
    local fmt="%Y"
    while getopts "amc" opt; do
        case "$opt" in
            a) fmt="%X" ;;
            m) fmt="%Y" ;;
            c) fmt="%Z" ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $(( OPTIND - 1))
    [[ $(stat -c "$fmt" "$1") > $(stat -c "$fmt" "$2") ]]
}

if nt -c file_a file_b; then
    echo file_a has a newer ctime than file_b
fi
```